# Destroy existing Label Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to run multiple calculations with UI using Tkinter in python where i have to display all the outputs for all the calculations. The problem is, the output for the first calculation is fine but the outputs for further calculations seems to be calculated out of default values.  I came to know that i should destroy first label in order to output the second calculation, but when i try to destroy my first label, i could not. The code i tried is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

def funcname():
#My calculations
   GMT = GMT_user.get()
   lat = lat_deg_user.get()

   E = GMT * 365
   Eqntime_label.configure(text=E)


   Elevation = E/lat
   Elevation_label.configure(text=Elevation)

nUI_pgm = Tk()
GMT_user = DoubleVar()
lat_deg_user = DoubleVar()

nlabel_time = Label(text = "Enter time in accordance to GMT in decimal").pack()
nEntry_time = Entry(nUI_pgm, textvariable = GMT_user).pack()

nlabel_Long = Label(text = "Enter Longitude in Decimal Degrees").pack()
nEntry_Long = Entry(nUI_pgm, textvariable = lat_deg_user).pack()

nbutton = Button(nUI_pgm, text = "Calculate", command = funcname).pack()


#Displaying results

nlabel_E = Label (text = "The Equation of Time is").pack()
Eqntime_label = Label(nUI_pgm, text="")
Eqntime_label.pack()
#when i try
Eqntime_label.destroy() # this doesn't work

nlabel_Elevation = Label(text = "The Elevation of the sun is").pack()
Elevation_label = Label(nUI_pgm, text="")
Elevation_label.pack()

nUI_pgm.mainloop()
```

Here I have to destroy the Eqntime_label after the result is displayed in order to output Elevation_label too. What should i do??

Comment: you need to show more code that would reproduce your issue. Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: @AnandSKumar Just editted my codes..

Comment: please edit. it is not clear which code is under `def funcname()`. Remember: minimal, verifiable example. Current code would crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several mistakes:

```
def funcname()
GMT = GMT_user.get()
```

You are missing a colon on first line, and indent on second ->

```
def funcname():
    GMT = GMT_user.get()
```

Wrong variable name here (and `pack` returns None):

```
Entry_Long = Entry(nUI_pgm, textvariable = long_deg_user).pack()
```

must be:

```
Entry(nGui_pgm, textvariable = lat_deg_user).pack()
```

"I came to know that i should destroy first label in order to output the second calculation" : nope, the `configure` method is the good one. So remove:

```
Eqntime_label.destroy()
```

Answer (score 1):

A version using `set` instead of `configure` which is more in line with other variable definitions in your code.
Also, you must indent all lines corresponding to function.
For the rest, already explained in other answers.

```
from tkinter import *

def funcname():
    #My calculations
    GMT = GMT_user.get()
    lat = lat_deg_user.get()

    E = GMT * 365
    Elevation = E/lat

    etime.set(E)
    elevation.set(Elevation)


root = Tk()

# Getting user input
GMT_user = DoubleVar()
lat_deg_user = DoubleVar()

Label(root, text="Enter time in accordance to GMT in decimal").pack()
nEntry_time = Entry(root, textvariable=GMT_user).pack()

Label(root, text="Enter Latitude in Decimal Degrees").pack()
nEntry_Long = Entry(root, textvariable=lat_deg_user).pack()

nbutton = Button(root, text="Calculate", command=funcname).pack()

# Displaying results
etime = StringVar()
elevation = StringVar()

Label(text="The Equation of Time is").pack()
Eqntime_label = Label(root, textvariable=etime)
Eqntime_label.pack()

Label(text="The Elevation of the sun is").pack()
Elevation_label = Label(root, textvariable=elevation)
Elevation_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```